# Element-UI pagination Inertia Link

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, element-ui, element-plus

I try to add the links to my pagination I use element-ui and Inertiajs laravel , help please

```js
<el-pagination
 
          v-if="items.last_page > 1"
          background
          layout="total, prev, pager, next"
          :total="items.total"
          :page-size="items.per_page"
          @current-change="handleCurrentChange ????"
        />
```

the controller :

```
public function index()
    {
        $items= Item::latest()->paginate();

        return Inertia::render('Item/Index', ['items'=>$items]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

update if any one have solution to set route for links something like this :

```
const handleCurrentChange = (id) => {
  Inertia.get(route('items.links', id))
}
```